# faced 'Spring Security & whitelabel Error 404' at the very first step

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-security

I just started making
Springboot starter project with gradle

first of all, i can't understand why i see security log-in page even when i set config permitAll
and secondly, i see 404 error after i log-in correctly

**this is my SecurityConfig**

```
package config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity   
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //super.configure(http);
        
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().permitAll();  
    }

}
```

**this is the controller**

```
package notice;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ApiNoticeController {
    
    @GetMapping("/api/notice")
    public String noticeSting() {
        return "notice";
    }
}
```

**dependencies**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

**console**
2022-03-23 18:50:34.733  INFO 27256 --- [           main] com.example.demo.PracticeApplication     : Starting PracticeApplication using Java 17.0.1 on DESKTOP-JBB51IM with PID 27256 (C:\Users\user1\Desktop\CRUD\practice\bin\main started by user1 in C:\Users\user1\Desktop\CRUD\practice)
2022-03-23 18:50:34.740  INFO 27256 --- [           main] com.example.demo.PracticeApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-03-23 18:50:36.429  INFO 27256 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-03-23 18:50:36.453  INFO 27256 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 8 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-03-23 18:50:37.521  INFO 27256 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-03-23 18:50:37.538  INFO 27256 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-03-23 18:50:37.538  INFO 27256 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
2022-03-23 18:50:37.773  INFO 27256 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-03-23 18:50:37.774  INFO 27256 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2922 ms
2022-03-23 18:50:38.067  INFO 27256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-03-23 18:50:38.415  INFO 27256 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2022-03-23 18:50:38.508  INFO 27256 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-03-23 18:50:38.614  INFO 27256 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.5.Final
2022-03-23 18:50:39.009  INFO 27256 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-03-23 18:50:39.252  INFO 27256 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2022-03-23 18:50:39.781  INFO 27256 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2022-03-23 18:50:39.801  INFO 27256 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2022-03-23 18:50:39.866  WARN 27256 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2022-03-23 18:50:40.609  INFO 27256 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration :

Using generated security password: ****

2022-03-23 18:50:40.934  INFO 27256 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will not secure any request
2022-03-23 18:50:41.124  INFO 27256 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2022-03-23 18:50:41.145  INFO 27256 --- [           main] com.example.demo.PracticeApplication     : Started PracticeApplication in 7.185 seconds (JVM running for 9.471)
2022-03-23 18:50:48.680  INFO 27256 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-03-23 18:50:48.680  INFO 27256 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2022-03-23 18:50:48.681  INFO 27256 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2022-03-23 18:50:49.157  WARN 27256 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase        : Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [397] milliseconds.

it worked well at first, returning URL "http://localhost:8080/api/notice" & String "notice"
but suddenly not working...

What I know and saw is that I used @RestController so i don't need html view resolver...

i also tried with configuration -
// super.configure(http);
super.configure(http);

both...didn't work

Comment: Enable spring security debug logs and the logs will tell exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was a stupid mistake.... as you can see in the package name, i set the package path wrong. thanks everybody for reading